# Подсчет количества флажков с установленной галочкой на jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

```html
<ul class="" class="category2">
    <li class="">
 <a href="#" id="titlecategories">
     Титл
 </a>
    </li>
    <li class="subcategory2" >
 <a href="#">
     <input checked="" name="filter[]" id="filtercheckbox11" value="11" type="checkbox">
     Текст-Текст-Текст-
 </a>
    </li>
    <li class="subcategory2" >
  <a href="#">
     <input name="filter[]" id="filtercheckbox2" value="2" type="checkbox">
     Текст-Текст-Текст-Текст-
 </a>
    </li>
    <li class="subcategory2">
 <a href="#">
    <input checked="" name="filter[]" id="filtercheckbox4" value="4"  type="checkbox">
    Текст-Текст-Текст-Текст-
       </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Нужно с помощью `jquery` подсчитать сколько чекбоксов отмечено на странице. Таких примеров на странице естественно несколько. Они отличаются классами `category` и `subcategory`. Например сколько в `category2` отмеченных чекбоксов `subcategory2` и т. д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Erm, автор все таки хотел подсчет по всем категориям и субкатегориям, возможно что-то подобное?

```js
var countChecked = function() {
  var n = $('.category2 input:checked').length;
  $('div').text(n + ' выбрано!');
};
countChecked();

$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', countChecked);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="category2">
  <li class="">
    <a href="#" id="titlecategories">
     Титл
 </a>
  </li>
  <li class="subcategory2">
    <a href="#">
      <input checked="" name="filter[]" id="filtercheckbox11" value="11" type="checkbox"> Текст-Текст-Текст-
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="subcategory2">
    <a href="#">
      <input name="filter[]" id="filtercheckbox2" value="2" type="checkbox"> Текст-Текст-Текст-Текст-
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="subcategory2">
    <a href="#">
      <input checked="" name="filter[]" id="filtercheckbox4" value="4" type="checkbox"> Текст-Текст-Текст-Текст-
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div></div>
```

**p.s. @Erm переделал ваш код, надеюсь вы не против**

Comment: Да код рабочий, спасибо. Но все же мне именно нужно сделать подсчет внутри класса category2

Comment: @skillful, поправил, вы так имеете ввиду? можно более детально и подробно тогда объяснить, что и как должно быть

Comment: var n = $('input:checked').length; данный код подсчитает все выделенные чекбоксы на всей странице. А мне нужно только внутри определенного класса category2, в коде как в первом сообщении

Comment: @skillful, о как просто все оказалось, поправил

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить такой скрипт, тут выводит просто в `<div>`, но можно и указать определенный `class/id` элемента для всех необходимых параметров.

```js
var countChecked = function() {
  var n = $('input:checked').length;
  $('div').text(n + ' выбрано!');
};
countChecked();

$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', countChecked);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="" class="category2">
  <li class="">
    <a href="#" id="titlecategories">
     Титл
 </a>
  </li>
  <li class="subcategory2">
    <a href="#">
      <input checked="" name="filter[]" id="filtercheckbox11" value="11" type="checkbox"> Текст-Текст-Текст-
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="subcategory2">
    <a href="#">
      <input name="filter[]" id="filtercheckbox2" value="2" type="checkbox"> Текст-Текст-Текст-Текст-
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="subcategory2">
    <a href="#">
      <input checked="" name="filter[]" id="filtercheckbox4" value="4" type="checkbox"> Текст-Текст-Текст-Текст-
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Да, спасибо это работает. Но мне нужно сделать подсчет внутри класса category2